# jQuery: Using a Widget after an HTML append

Tags: jquery, html, dom, widget, append

I have a dynamic page in which I create some elements (HTML Inputs) based on some DataBase configurations.

Let's say, my initial HTML of that page may have no controls (apart from the Masterpage ones) and they will be created after pressing a button, just for example.

After adding those controls, having a div and using `.append`, I need to use a Widget on some SELECT elements that were newly created (as found in the [jQuery UI Multiple Select Widget](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/)).

Thing is, that won't work.

I also made this test:

- Put a SELECT element on the HTML page (right on the html, not dynamically as I am trying to).
- If I start the widget on the `$(document).ready` function, it's starts ok and becomes multi-selectable.
- Commenting the above function, if I only start the widget on a button click, the SELECT won't become multi-selectable.

Can you, please, help me? Is this because of some DOM thing? Here's a snippet from this "engine": http://jsfiddle.net/SWyw9/

Answer (score 2):

Its too late to answer but, I thought this answer may help future designers/developers.
We know that there's a delegate() function in jquery to bind events handlers to dynamically added elements.

I feel this delegate() function can be used in your case.
Check out the following code snippet.

```
// Here you are using delegate to attach mouse over event handler to the existing elements as well as elements which will be added dynamically in future.
$('#myContainer').delegate('.myDraggableClass', 'mouseenter', function() {

  var $this = $(this);
  // Checking whether or not the widget is applied to the element.
  if(!$this.is(':data(draggable)')) {

    // As widget is not applied, applying it.
    $this.draggable({ /* configure draggable here */  });
  }
});
```

Code snippet is copied from the below given link.
Check out for more details:
http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/07/configuring-ui-widgets-and-interactions-with-live/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what you are asking.

It seems like it is a binding issue. You can't bind events to elements that don't exist (dynamic elements) unless you use bind(), which has been depreciated, or the new "on."

```
$("#body-id").on("click", ".widget-button", function(event){
    //do something
});
```

This attaches the button click to the body tag with an id of body-id. The body then listens for future widget-button clicks since the body exists on ready when the dynamic widget does not.

Not sure if this is what you are asking.

OK I forked your fiddle into this:
http://jsfiddle.net/TheFiddler/USHc5/4/

Is that what you are after?

1) Create an array of types
2) Pass that to BuildHTML
3) Split out the props
4) Switch case for each
5) Render new html

Comment: Let me try to give some more details on what I am really doing:

- My page starts with almost no elements on it, just some fixed ones
- After I select a Category and a SubCategory, I use a database table to give me the elements that should be constructed: Checkboxs, text inputs, selects, etc.
- With that information that comes from the DB, also comes if there's any widget to be applied after I append the generated element HTML to my DIV

So, I only call the widget start on the element once it's already on my DIV. There's no button I need to click, it was just an example.

Comment: I modified my answer above with a response fiddle.